# What are the good online tutorials to learn Hibernate and Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring

What are the good online tutorials to learn Hibernate and Spring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best book to learn Spring and Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460739/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-spring-and-hibernate)

Comment: @Turbochrgd  Sorry about this. I should have used google :(

Comment: [video-tutorial-on-spring-and-hibernate](http://basics-in-java.blogspot.in/2014/02/video-tutorial-on-spring-and-hibernate.html)

Comment: Just for Hibernate you might the video training course on Hibernate and JPA fundamentals, recently released by http://mavenedge.com, quite useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with this article from Martin Fowler [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

This would give you an insight into what really is the role of Spring. And then dive into using [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

[This link](http://www.capcourse.com/Library/Spring+Hibernate/Spring+Hibernate_20_32.pdf) is great for Hibernate and Spring Integration.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

These are the links you might want to check out for spring tutorials and examples. You can find all of them easily, but it is good to have them in a hand. I also recommend you to go through [official documentation](http://www.springsource.org/documentation)

1. [Spring by example](http://springbyexample.org/)
2. [Spring MVC 3](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)
3. [Tutorial: Working with Spring 3 MVC and HTML Forms](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2395)
4. [The Spring PetClinic Application](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html)