# Developing web application in eclipse by wicket-hibernate-spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, wicket

I want to develop a web application or project in eclipse by wicket-hibernate-spring. I have searched Google for a step-by-step tutorial but I found nothing which can direct me to the right path. I am beginner in Java Web Development. So any information regarding this will be very helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would recommend:

1. [Spring 3 & Hibernate using Maven and Eclispe](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/11/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example.html)
2. Here is a [related StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320841/what-are-the-good-online-tutorials-to-learn-hibernate-and-spring/5321843#5321843).

I would also recommend you to take a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). [Follow this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-springroo1/?ca=drs-) to get upto speed with Spring Roo.

There is [wicket add on too](http://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-wicket-addon/) for Roo.

Hope that helps.